# Validity of binomial expansion for any power

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I know that
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}x^2+\\
\dots+\frac {n(n-1)\dots(n-r+1)}{r!}x^r\text.$$
I know that this formula is valid for any real number n, provided that $|x|<1$. The formula extends infinitely for a negative value of $n$, and terminates for a positive value of $n$. Is there a formula for a case where $|x|>1$? Why is this formula applicable only for $|x|<1$?

Comment: I don't have the background to disagree here, but I'm not sure you can talk about factorials of a non-positive integer without a $\Gamma$ function (and, specifically, I'm including positive non-integers here, i.e. positive rational non-integers as needing a definition of the $\Gamma$ function)...

Comment: I suggest studying (way beyond my understanding) the "real continuation" of a function: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. Why did you delete your answer ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Jared If the right side is replaced by an infinite sum then  OP's formula is valid for all real $n$ when $|x|<1$.

Comment: "terminates for a positive value of $n$": no, $n$ needs to be natural. In that case, any $x$ works.

Comment: For an infinite series to converge, the general term must tend to zero, which is not the case when $|x|>1$. Entire series converge "up to the nearest singularity", here $x=-1$.

Comment: $(1+x)^n$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere, except when $n$ is non-natural and $x=-1$. This is enough to break convergence where $|x|>|-1|$.

Comment: Ok: instead of asking answerers, How do you know that this is valid, for instance, for $n = 0.5$ (not even irrational)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x<-1$ note that $(1+x)^{n}$ is not defined for all real $n$. For $x>1$ the series on the right is not convergent. However, you can get an expansion for $x>1$ using the fact that $(1+x)^{n}=x^{n} (1+\frac 1 x)^{n}$ and using the expansion of $(1+\frac 1 x)^{n}$ (which is valid sinec $|\frac 1  x| <1$ in this case).

Comment: I feel like you're using integer $n$ here (a Lorentz series), but OP asked about real $n$.

Comment: @Jared No, I am not assuming that $n$ is an integer. I has to avoid $x <-1$ and I have corrected the answer.

Comment: I just want to make clear that I'm just asking for clarification here: How can you say you're not assuming $n$ is a positive integer when the formula involves $n!$?

Comment: @Jared: Laurent, not Lorentz !

Comment: @IAmAGuest Yes, thank you for clarifying--dude's it's been a while..

Comment: @Jared $r$ is a running integer variable in the expansion and it involes $r!$ There is no $n!$ anywhere.

Comment: What is the expansion for $\left(1 +x\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ and how is related to the geometric series? I'm not asking this to be rude, I'm asking this because you're 275k and I assume you can explain.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It's not the real continuation of a Taylor series--that's the problem...maybe I'm misinterpreting this question (it's happened numerous times before).

Comment: @Jared Expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2}$ for $|x|<1$ is a very basic result in Calculus and many books have it. You should make an attempt to find a proof yourself.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't know what to say to that...yeah, it's quite different than this Taylor expansion, because $n$ isn't an integer. But OP specifically asked for real $n$--which is my point: it's way more complicated than a Taylor/Maclaurin series.

Comment: @Jared Note that anyway, *n!* can be defined for noninteger $n$ as $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. It's really not a problem. And not it's not *"way more complicated"*, it's *also* a Taylor series.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut So 1) see the first comment on this question and 2) I disagree that it's not "way more complicated"...it is...it's the real continuation of the factorial which is far from trivial.

Comment: @Jared You don't *need* the $\Gamma$ function to write the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^n$ for noninteger $n$. The (more usual?) formula involves products $n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)$ as in your question, which you can write using the binomial coefficient $n\choose r$ with noninteger $n$ (does not require the $\Gamma$ function, it's only an extension of the definition and a shortcut for the product). Just write down the derivatives, it's really *just* Taylor's formula. And there is no $n!$ anywhere, only $r!$.

Answer (score 0):

The series you have written is valid for any real value of $x$ if $n$ is zero or a natural number. In this case your expansion is an identity and you get a polynomial of degree $n+1$ in $x$.

But if $n$ is negative integer or non integral, your expansion is valid only for |x|<1 and the series is infinite and convergent.

For example
$$(1+x)^4=1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4.$$
$$(1+x)^{4.3}=1+4.3x+(4.3*3.3)x^2/2+(4.3*3.3*3.2)x^3/6+........$$
$$(1+x)^{-4.3}=1-4.3x+(4.3*5.3)x^2/2-(4.3*5.3*6.3)x^3/6+........$$
$$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+......., \text{if}~ |x|<1$$
$$(1+1/3)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}(1/3)-\frac{1.1}{2.2.2!}(1/3)^2+\frac{1.1.3}{2.2.2.3!}(1/3)^3+.....$$

Comment: What about positive reals ?

Comment: See my edir. For negative integers or non integral (positive /negatiove) values of $n$, we get an infinite series. which is valid if ${x}<1$.